# How to "run this program from begining after else statement"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If user inputs a number which is outside the code then i want to run the program again from start in continuation.

```
number = input("Enter your number up to 100 : ")

while int(number) < 100:
     print(number)

else:
    print("\n**The number is outside the Limit.**")
```

Comment: Put `number = input("Enter your number up to 100 : ")` inside the loop. Change your orphaned `else` to an `if`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to be using the 'while' in your code? I'm not sure what you need but consider this instead:

```
while True:
    number = input("Enter your number up to 100 : ")
    if int(number) < 100:
        print(number)
        break
    else:
        print("\n**The number is outside the Limit.**")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the simplest:

```
while True:
    number = input("Enter your number up to 100 : ")
    if int(number) < 100:
        print(number)
        break
    print("\n**The number is outside the Limit.**")
```

But what if the user enters a non-numeric value? You will throw an exception when you try to convert the string to an int. So:

```
while True:
    number = input("Enter your number up to 100 : ")
    try:
        if int(number) < 100:
            print(number)
            break
        print("\n**The number is outside the Limit.**")
    except ValueError:
        print("You did not enter a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to issue the first prompt, then continuously accept user input unless it is over the limit, in which case print the warning and the first prompt again...

You need to collect input separately from the first prompt in this case:

```
while True:
    print("Enter your number up to 100:")
    while True:
        number = int(input())
        if number < 100:
            print("number is:", number)
        else:
            print("number is outside the limit")
            break
```

sample output:

```
Enter your number up to 100:
12
number is: 12
123
number is outside the limit
Enter your number up to 100:
12
number is: 12
3
number is: 3
```

Of course, I may not have interpreted your question correctly, but I hope this helps.